# Como cambiar algunas columnas de un tipo a otro tipo en pyspark de una lista de tablas en hive

Tags: pyspark, hive

Tengo una lista de tablas en hive pero el nombre de sus esquemas los tengo en una tabla mysql, las uno para tener la lista de tablas con sus esquemas, luego por cada fila de esa lista, selecciono los campos que sean de tipo datetime2 y los convierto a timestamp, luego la tabla convertida la guardo a MS-SQL, pero al salvarla me sigue dando error en campo de tipo datetime2 con valor fuera de rango.

```
# Unir tablas de Hive y MySQL por nombre de tabla
df_hive_tables = df_hive_tables.withColumn('utableName', 
upper(df_hive_tables['tableName']))
df_result = df_hive_tables.join(df_mysql_tables, df_hive_tables.utableName == 
df_mysql_tables.tabla, "inner")
dataframes_converted: list[Any] = []

# Guardar cada tabla de Hadoop en MS-SQL con prefijo de esquema correspondiente
for row in df_result.rdd.collect():
    esquema = row["esquema"]
    tabla_hadoop = row["tableName"]
    if df_result.schema["tableName"].dataType == "datetime2":
        converted_df: object = converted_df.withColumn(column, col(column).cast("timestamp"))
    dataframes_converted.append(converted_df)`
```